# Entity Framework uses SqlCeCommand when I try to connect to Azure database

Tags: frameworks, azure, entity

I am using two databases in the project: Azure and Sql Compact. Entity Framework was generated using Compact database, but now I am trying to use it to connect to Azure database with the same schema passing to Context constructor Azure connection string:

but when it tries to get some data it gives me the exception:
"SqlCeCommand.CommandTimeout does not support non-zero values."

Why it uses Compact command if provider is specified correctly? How I can fix this?

Comment: My connection string: <add name="AzureConnectionString" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DbModel.csdl|res://*/DbModel.ssdl|res://*/DbModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=tcp:some.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=somedb;Integrated Security=False;User ID=someuser;Password=somepsd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/82017/Preparing-an-Entity-Framework-model-for-multi-prov.aspx

Answer (score 0):

this may not have been the cause of your issue but I received this error when I had manually set the command timeout for the SqlCeCommand that I was using to connect to my Compact Edition database.

This is the setting I removed:

```
    cecmd.CommandTimeout = 720;
```

I hope this helps someone else!